# Angular 15 routing only to default page despite of any path

Tags: angular, typescript, url-routing, angular-routing, angular15

I am creating a new Angular 15 application and for now its going to have only one page and that will be the landing page also. How can I restrict or redirect to the default landing page always when user attempts to launch with different path name?

For example:

- If user attempts to load https://localhost:6150/hello i need to redirect to https://localhost:6150/landingpage.
- If user attempts to load https://localhost:6150/ i need to redirect to https://localhost:6150/landingpage.

Redirection should happen only once in any of the above scenario.

Comment: You can define the default route to be `landingpage` and set up a [redirect](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects) for the wiidcard `**` route. Ideally the wildcard route should be some sort of "404" page, but you can also just redirect to a valid page instead.

Comment: @Cuzy - Let me test after adding the wildcard route to my landing page.